# Getting Error while Running Gstreamer C++ Examples

Tags: c++, windows, gstreamer-1.0

I am getting following error while running https://github.com/pakcell/GstreamerExample It relates to gobject-2.0.lib. I have seen https://dll-helper.xiaolee.net/p/libgobject-2_0-0_dll.html where I can download the .dll but where would I place it on the computer? Running Gstreamer 1.16.2
[image]

Comment: In the same dir as the exe

Comment: Not able to find any .dll on my pc under gstreamer-1.0 folder

Comment: Now it is complaining about glib-2.0.0. Why it needs the .dll if I have already provided path to .lib?

Answer (score 0):

Install gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-1.16.2.msi. Change the folder name from x86_64 to x86_64_1 and install gstreamer-1.0-mingw-x86_64-1.16.2 (1).msi and now copy the lib folder contents from  x86_64 to x86_64_1. Now rename x86_64 to x86_64_2. And rename x86_64_1 to x86_64. That will solve the issue. Gstreamer folks have seperated .dll and .h in different installers which is inconvenient. Not sure why but this solve it.